# ol3 modify interaction customization

Tags: openlayers, extents

I'm trying to create a ol.interaction.Modify() to adjust a bounding box's edges and position. In OpenLayers 2 I used TransformFeature Control and There were options to configure the transformation. How could the feature be modified in ol3 without changing the shape? 
I also want to add vertices as in ol2.
If there's no other way then implementing a new interaction, could you provide some resources on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out already, there is nothing like a TransformFeature control in ol3 currently. However, it is quite easy to create a custom interaction that deals with specific feature modifications. For inspiration, you can look at the official [drag-features](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/examples/drag-features.html) example.

In your case, you will probably analyze the coordinate in the `handleDownEvent` function and determine the quadrant of your box and the proximity to the box corners. By doing so, you can conditionally set the behavior of the `handleDragEvent` function to either change one of the corner coordinates, or to drag the box as shown in the example.